# Creating a points system for my connect 4 maths game

Tags: python, events, integer, pygame

I am trying to add a point every time a user gets an answer correct and take away a point if the are incorrect in my connect 4 maths game. In the game the user drops a counter into the place the want and the question pops up and waits for an answer so that it can proceed. Everything in this code works but I am just trying to make a points system. This just resets the score value every time they answer a question. Thanks for the help!

```
N = random.randint(0, 14) 
SCORE = 0

with open("QUESTIONS.txt") as QUESTIONS, open("ANSWERS.txt") as ANSWERS:
    QUESTIONdata = QUESTIONS.readlines()
    ANSWERdata = ANSWERS.readlines()
    x = QUESTIONdata[N]
    y = ANSWERdata[N]
    txtbx = inputbox.Input(maxlength=45, color=(169,37,44), prompt = x[:-1])


    while True:

        events = pygame.event.get()
        txtanswer = txtbx.update(events)
        txtbx.draw(DISPLAYWINDOW)
        pygame.display.flip()
        drawBoard(mainBoard)

        B = pygame.Surface((630, 540), pygame.SRCALPHA)   
        B.fill((0,0,0,128))
        DISPLAYWINDOW.blit(B, (XMARGIN, YMARGIN))

        for event in events:
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RETURN:
                    user_answer = str(txtbx.value)
                    try:
                        if (user_answer) == str(y[:-1]):
                            print("correct")
                            SCORE += 1
                            print(SCORE)
                            return

                        else:
                            turn = AI
                            print("incorrect")
                            print(SCORE)
                            SCORE += -1
                            print(SCORE)
                            return

                    except ValueError:
                        turn = AI
                        print("value errr")
                        SCORE += -1
                        return

            elif event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return
```

Comment: You know `-=` is a thing, right?

Comment: Is this the only place you use score?

Comment: Yeah but changing it to SCORE -= 1 outputs the same value

Comment: @Calpratt yes it is the only place I use it.

Comment: I see you're using returns.. can you post the full function?

Comment: and how you're calling it

Comment: @Calpratt http://i.imgur.com/S9IjA0H.png shows it being called and http://i.imgur.com/WWkYIhC.png

Comment: You definitely do not include enough information nor have you really completed you code much... But what are you returning to???

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 http://i.imgur.com/S9IjA0H.png

Comment: Yes it is being called, but your returning thus ending the script. If this is your full code then you need to read some tutorials or something to improve on what you are doing. No offense it just would help.

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 yeah sorry i guess I am quite new, here is my full code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4isti98zpjcdlep/Connect4MathsChallenge.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your score should be a global variable I'm not sure if your whole script is in one file, but if it isn't what you could do is return the score you want to change. Then follow the advice from everyone, so in your `main()` just add SCORE as a global variable.

```
global SCORE
```

This should fix the problem you're running in to. And just fyi for next time you post a question on SO you need to include a bit more information, and more relevant code. You didn't include all of the relevant code.

Better yet here's a better solution.

in here I'm changing one slight thing.

```
while True: # main loop 

    if turn == PLAYER: 
        # PLAYER's turn. 
        getPLAYERMove(mainBoard, RED) 
        changeOfScore = askquestions(mainBoard, RED) 
        SCORE += changeOfScore
```

And then in the askquestions function return the amount you want to change the SCORE by.

Example:

```
return 1
```

or

```
return -1
```

Comment: @user3470107 No problem let me know if it works for you.